# JavaScript not executing on external domain

Tags: javascript, jquery, wordpress, ubuntu

I have a wordpress site that we have just launched and I am trying to embed some ads into it from a joomla site we have setup as an ad manager.

The ad manager provides a script with which to embed an advertising zone. I've used this a lot in the past and it always just worked. Trying to get the script to work on this new server isn't playing ball.

I made the following `test.php` file and uploaded it to both the ad server and the wordpress site. If I load it on the ad server it pulls the ad, if I open it on the wordpress server the script doesn't seem to execute. I also tried using the jquery function `getScript`, this worked on the ad server but not the wordpress one.

```
<!doctype html>
<html>
<head></head>
<body>
  <script type="text/javascript" language="javascript" src="http://ads.childmags.com.au/index.php?option=com_adagency&controller=adagencyAds&task=remote_ad&tmpl=component&format=raw&zid=103"></script>
</body>
</html>


<!doctype html>
<html>
<head>
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
  <script>$.getScript("http://ads.childmags.com.au/index.php?option=com_adagency&controller=adagencyAds&task=remote_ad&tmpl=component&format=raw&zid=103")</script>
</body>
</html>
```

Is it likely to be the wordpress server config that needs changing? Is there anyway to get around this?

Comment: Are any errors logged at `console` or server?

Comment: What does the fox say? `"A call to document.write() from an asynchronously-loaded external script was ignored."` - so, you've got no chance

Comment: @JaromandaX he could override `document.write` probably so there is a little hope

Comment: Assuming he owns `ads.childmags.com.au` of course

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are using script of one site to another site , so it may can be  cross origin issue.
To resolve this you have to add crossorigin="anonymous"
Like :- `<script type="text/javascript" crossorigin="anonymous" language="javascript" src="http://ads.childmags.com.au/index.php?option=com_adagency&controller=adagencyAds&task=remote_ad&tmpl=component&format=raw&zid=103"></script>`

Crossorigin attribute is present when a request is loaded using 'CORS' which is now a requirement of SRI checking when not loaded from the 'same-origin'.

Unfortunately Wordpress can't proceed attributes properly on enqueued scripts.